# How to fetch day string from a Calendar day

Tags: java

This is what I use to fetch the string corresponding to a day. Is there a simpler method

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
private static final Map<Integer, String> weekDays = Collections
        .unmodifiableMap(new HashMap<Integer, String>() {
            {
                put(Calendar.SUNDAY, "sunday");
                put(Calendar.MONDAY, "monday");
                put(Calendar.TUESDAY, "tuesday");
                put(Calendar.WEDNESDAY, "wednesday");
                put(Calendar.THURSDAY, "thursday");
                put(Calendar.FRIDAY, "friday");
                put(Calendar.SATURDAY, "saturday");
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`Calendar.getDisplayName(int field, int style, Locale locale)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#getDisplayName(int,%20int,%20java.util.Locale)) method:

```
Calendar.getInstance().getDisplayName(Calendar.FRIDAY, Calendar.LONG, Locale.ENGLISH));
```

This will give you `"Friday"` as a String.

The method consumes three parameters:

1. `field` is the `Calendar`'s field name you want to have displayed. For example, `Calendar.FRIDAY` or `Calendar.MARCH`.
2. `style` is either `Calenday.SHORT` or `Calendar.LONG`, depending on what you need (long name or short name).
3. `locale` the locale for the string representation.